# How to ensure that my amplify request is completed before returning a value?

Tags: javascript, ajax, caching, asynchronous

In one of my files, I make a call as follows:

```
var jobsString = getDropdownJobs();
```

It calls this function :

```
function getDropdownJobs() {

    var jobsString = amplify.store("JobsList");

    if (typeof jobsString === 'undefined') {

        // Amplify sends a request for getJobs, if it exists in cache, it will return that value.
        // If it does not exist in cache, it will make the AJAX request.
        amplify.request("getJobs", function (data) {

            // Leave a blank option for the default of no selection.
            var jobsString = '<option value=""></option>';
            // Append each of the options to the jobsString.
            $.each(data.jobs, function () {
                jobsString += "<option " + "value=" + this.JobNo_ + ">" + this.JobNo_ + " : " + this.Description + this.Description2 + "</option>";
            });
            // Store the jobsString to be used later.
            amplify.store("JobsList", jobsString);

        });
    }
    return jobsString;

}
```

Where the amplify definition of `"GetJobs"` is :

```
amplify.request.define("getJobs", "ajax", {
    url: "../api/Job/Jobs",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    cache: "persist"
});
```

Whenever it returns, it's undefined. I put "async: false" in the AJAX definition and it didn't change anything.

How can I make sure that the value is there before returning?

Comment: have a look at [`$.Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Amplify, but [its API](http://amplifyjs.com/api/request/) says

> Requests made through `amplify.request` will always be resolved asynchronously

So, you'll have to pass a callback into `getDropdownJobs`, to be executed after `jobsString` is filled, and any code that relies on the value goes in it.

Alternatively you could use Amplify's pub/sub system to subscribe an event for when `jobsString` is filled and publish to it during `getDropdownJobs`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I'm misunderstanding your question, but every time you do something like this, an asynchronous requests, you need to wait for the answer. Before I suggest an alternative some quick tips I tend to follow:

- Usually methods like your `getJobsDropdown` don't return anything, or potentially they can return promises. Take a look at [jquery promises](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) or this article for more advanced material on [chaining](http://shangbang.me/chaining-asynchronous-calls-with-q-and-jquery) those same promises.
- The most trivial thing you can use is a callback, some method on the context on the invoker of `getJobsDropdown` where you want to process the data. This will allow you to *resume* your program when the data is ready.

Try this:

```
function getDropdownJobs(callback) {

    // some code (...)

    amplify.request("getJobs", function (data) {

       // your processing and when done
       callback();

    });
}
```

Potentially you can pass the data in the callback. A usual call of the `getDropdownJobs` would be:

```
function processResults() { // This is your callback }

function getData() {

    // This is where you call getDropDownJobs
    getDropDownJobs(processResults);
}
```

Was this helpful? I hope so.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery and do not mind coupling amplify with the jQuery framework you can use this plugin, allowing you to utilise jQuery deferred objects:

[amplify-request-deferred plugin](https://github.com/elijahmanor/amplify-request-deferred)

Here is an article with some background information and an overview of the plugin usage:

[Adding jQuery Deferred Support to AmplifyJS Request](http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/10/adding-jquery-deferred-support-to.html)